# Regex for matching second "(text)" appearance on a given line

Tags: regex, special-characters

I have some text with the following structure for the lines:

```
(short text)  some text here (longer explanation)
```

Which is the proper regexp to match the second parenthesis set, i.e., "(longer explanation)" ?

thanks

Comment: Are there always two sets in a line? Do you have to take care of nested parenthesis?

Comment: `.*?\([^\(]+\K\([\w\s]+\)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will work fine: `/.*?\([^\(]+\K\([\w\s]+\)/s`

[Test this regex here.](https://regex101.com/r/sKlhBB/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this one (which accepts nested parenthesis in the longer explanation).

`\(.*?\).*?(\(.*\))(?!\))`

The shorter text has to be in parenthesis (as specified in your question).